# How can extract a full link between two quotes using regular expressions?

Tags: .net, regex

I need to extract a link between two quotation marks in an html page. None of the links are exactly the same. I've used regular expressions to extract the url before but all the links are different. In other words, I'm trying to extract the link as a whole, no matter what it is from end to end. Can you do this with regular expressions?

Here's and example link: "http://scontent-b.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xpf1/t51.2885-15/10561055_469264259842770_1297380753_a.jpg"

Note that these link are all different. This is just one example. So how can extract the link from quote to quote as a whole using regular expressions?

Comment: Provide some sample raw input to show what comes before and after it.

Comment: Before and after what? The Link?

Comment: To make a long story short is there a way to extract a link from html page from end to end with out defining explicit regex expressions. I can extract the link but every link is different so that would require a new regex expression for every link. So is the a unified way to extract a link, from the beginning to the end, using the same regex expression for every link?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
//regex
href="([^"]*)"

//escaped
var pattern = "href=\"([^\"]*)\"";
```

http://regex101.com/r/pS8sZ1/1

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work. Thanks for your answer and link.

Comment: @user3888376 It should match any properly formatted href link. If you want more help, you need to provide an actual sample of what you need to match.

Comment: <img src="http://scontent-b.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xpf1/t51.2885-15/10561055_469264259842770_1297380753_a.jpg" width="220" heigh="220"></a>

Comment: @user3888376 that's not an HTML link, that's an image source. Just change href to src on the pattern. Also that's not valid HTML at all, it's missing a double quote at the end of the source.

Comment: @dcastro That is a valid HTML indeed, SO converts the text and shows as linq which trims the end and shows `...`(ellipsis). Mouse hover the link to see there is a `"` in the end

Comment: @dcastro Ah, Interesting. You feel comfortable answering questions from phone? Would you mind if I ask what phone you're using?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel it's an s4, but no I don't, at all. I was on my laptop when I answered the question but not anymore. I mainly use the SO app for commenting.